# Fail2Ban not working on Ubuntu 16.04 (Date issues)

Tags: fail2ban

I have a problem with Fail2Ban

```
2018-02-23 18:23:48,727 fail2ban.datedetector   [4859]: DEBUG   Matched time     template (?:DAY )?MON Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)?
2018-02-23 18:23:48,727 fail2ban.datedetector   [4859]: DEBUG   Got time  1519352628.000000 for "'Feb 23 10:23:48'" using template (?:DAY )?MON Day     24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)?
2018-02-23 18:23:48,727 fail2ban.filter         [4859]: DEBUG   Processing line with time:1519352628.0 and ip:158.140.140.217
2018-02-23 18:23:48,727 fail2ban.filter         [4859]: DEBUG   Ignore line since time 1519352628.0 < 1519381428.727771 - 600
```

It says "ignoring Line" because the time skew is greater than the inspection period.  However, this is not the case.

If indeed 1519352628.0 is derived from Feb 23, 10:23:48, then the other date: 1519381428.727771 must be wrong.

I have run tests for 'invalid user' hitting this repeatedly.  But Fail2ban is always ignoring the line.

I am positive I am getting Filter Matches within 1 second.

This is Ubuntu 16.04 and Fail2ban 0.9.3

Thanks for any help you might have!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a time zone issue on your machine that might cause the confusion. **Try to [set the correct time zone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323131/setting-timezone-from-terminal/323163) and restart both [rsyslogd](https://serverfault.com/questions/176747/how-to-restart-rsyslog-daemon-on-ubuntu/176749) and [fail2ban](https://www.booleanworld.com/protecting-ssh-fail2ban/).**

Regarding your debug log:

---

```
1519352628.0      = Feb 23 02:23:48
```

-> timestamp parsed from line in log file with time Feb 23 10:23:48 **- 08:00 time zone offset**!

---

```
1519381428.727771 = Feb 23 10:23:48
```

-> timestamp of current time when fail2ban processed the log.

Coincidently this is the same time as the time in the log file. **That's what makes it so confusing in this case**.

---

```
1519381428.727771 - 600 = Feb 23 10:13:48
```

-> limit for how long to look backwards in time in the log file since you've set `findtime  = 10m` in jail.conf.

Fail2ban 'correctly' ignores the log entry that appears to be older than 10 minutes, because of the set time zone -08:00.

---

btw:

If you need IPv6 support for banning, consider upgrading fail2ban to v0.10.x.

And there is also a brand new fail2ban version v0.11 (not yet marked stable, but running without issue for 1+ month on my machines) that has this wonderful new auto-increment bantime feature.

Comment: Bob, thanks.  Yes, the time zone is set correctly.  The zone is UTC+8:00 and the rtc is set to UTC.  The log file is in UTC (10:23am) and the clock date returns the proper time of 18:23.  It seems as if f2b doesn’t know my tz or it doesn’t know that the log file is logging UTC

Comment: Or rather, maybe the log file is logging local time (10:23am would be right) and is what I recall in the log.  02:23 would be UTC time.  In any case, how do I get them aligned?